# What conflicts might I encounter using MongoDB.Driver.Linq and System.Linq in the same namespace?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a question about MongoDB extension methods -

I want to import both `MongoDB.Driver.Linq` and `System.Linq` in the same namespace, where I am creating a Repository access layer, which will be used by a service layer in my API.

This allows me to do something like:

```
private readonly IMongoCollection _collection;

public Repository(IMongoDatabase database)
{
     _collection = database.GetCollection("SomeCollection");
}

// Method 1
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetByCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
     return _collection.AsQueryable().Where(expression);
}

// Method 2
public async Task<List<T>> GetByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
     return await _collection.AsQueryable().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
}
```

The problem is that I need `System.Linq` to allow *Method 1* to return an `IQueryable` object (therefore my service layer doesn't know the MongoDB implementation detail). Conversely, in *Method 2*, I need `MongoDB.Driver.Linq` to use the `.Where()` method to return an `IMongoQueryable` object and therefore use the `.ToListAsync` extension method.

Is having both of these in the namespace likely to cause issues? I have done a bit of reading that suggests it might!

Answer (score 1):

No, because the lambda signature between both methods are differents. There aren't any conflict between those extensions methods.